# Unable to find the first occurrence of substring using regex for set of values in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, substring, findall

I have a dataframe as below, i need to find only the first occurrence in a string for set of values.

I'm unable to use "find" function along with regex and dictionary. And if i use "findall" function, it is ofcourse finding all occurrence which is not what i need.

```
Text

51000/1-PLASTIC 150 Prange
51034/2-RUBBER KL 100 AA
51556/3-PAPER BD+CM 1 BOXT2
52345/1-FLOW IJ 10place 500 plastic
54975/1-DIVIDER PQR 100 BC
54975/1-SCALE DEF 555 AB Apple 
54975/1-PLASTIC ABC 4.6 BB plastic
```

Code:

```
import re

L = ['PLASTIC','RUBBER','PAPER','FLOW']
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)

df['Result'] = df['Text'].str.find(pat, flags=re.I).str.join(' ')
print(df)

df = df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)
df = df.replace(np.nan, "Not known", regex=True)
#df['Result'] = df['Result'].str.lower()
```

Expected Result:

```
Text                                                   Result

51000/1-PLASTIC 150 Prange                            Plastic
51034/2-RUBBER KL 100 AA                              Rubber
51556/3-PAPER BD+CM 1 BOXT2                           Paper
52345/1-FLOW IJ 10place 500 plastic                   Flow
54975/1-DIVIDER PQR 100 BC                            Not known
54975/1-SCALE DEF 555 AB Apple                        Not KNown 
54975/1-PLASTIC ABC 4.6 BB plastic                    Plastic
```

Error:

> TypeError: find() got an unexpected keyword argument 'flags'

Comment: can you try assigning the findall function to a variable & then doing `variable[0]`?

Comment: re.findall(regex, string)[0] , add a [0] to indicate 1st element of string in set of values. Simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) instead `find` with select first value of lists returned of `findall` by indexing `str[0]`:

```
import re

L = ['PLASTIC','RUBBER','PAPER','FLOW']
pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in L)

df['Result'] = df['Text'].str.findall(pat, flags=re.I).str[0]
```

Or use [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df['Result'] = df['Text'].str.extract('(' + pat + ')', flags=re.I)
```

---

Then convert missing values to `Not known`:

```
df['Result'] = df['Result'].fillna("Not known")
```

Last if necessary use [`Series.str.capitalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html):

```
df['Result'] = df['Result'].str.capitalize()
print (df)
                                   Text     Result
0            51000/1-PLASTIC 150 Prange    Plastic
1              51034/2-RUBBER KL 100 AA     Rubber
2           51556/3-PAPER BD+CM 1 BOXT2      Paper
3   52345/1-FLOW IJ 10place 500 plastic       Flow
4            54975/1-DIVIDER PQR 100 BC  Not known
5        54975/1-SCALE DEF 555 AB Apple  Not known
6  54975/1-PLASTIC ABC 4.6 BB plastic      Plastic
```